# ack doesn't recurse when specifying a file pattern

Tags: linux, grep, ack

```
ack "#define"
```

will recurse into subdirs and find files that contain #define. But I wanted to limit the search to *.h files, so I tried

```
ack "#define" *.h
```

and it doesn't recurse anymore. The only results come from files in the working directory.

Version:

> ack 1.96
>   Running under Perl 5.14.2 at /usr/bin/perl

Comment: See also [this](http://superuser.com/q/97910/1686), [this](http://superuser.com/q/332442/1686), [this](http://superuser.com/q/246061/1686), ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard **`*.h` is expanded by your shell**, and *ack* only receives individual files as its arguments – it doesn't have anywhere to recurse to.

To avoid this, specify the wildcard inside single or double quotes, but *ack* likely won't recognize it as a wildcard: `ack "#define" "*.h"`.

A better option is to use **`--hh`** to only include header files (see [`--help type`](http://betterthangrep.com/)), or **`-G '\.h$'`** to only include files matching the specified Perl regex.

Comment: In ack2 instead of the -G (which has been removed) you can do: ack -g '\.h$' | ack -x '#define'